# Why does constexpr not cause compilation to fail on index out of bounds

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I wrote a small helper function in my c++ project which should convert values of an `enum` to a predetermined list of strings. I wrote it like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

enum things{
    val1 = 0,
    val2,
    val3,
    val4
};

constexpr const char* things_strings[4] = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}; 

constexpr const char* get_thing_string(const things thing){
    return things_strings[static_cast<uint32_t>(thing)];
}

int main(){
  std::cout << get_thing_string(things::val1);
  std::cout << get_thing_string(static_cast<things>(12));
}
```

I expected this to fail compilation. I thought that by using `constexpr` I can prevent index out of bounds issues during compile time. Is there a way to enforce this in C++ 11?

Comment: In the future, in addition to tagging with a specific language version, also tag with c++. That way more users who can answer the question will see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you're calling the function at run time. If you call this function in a compile time context, e.g. by assigning to a `constexpr` variable, you'll get a compile time error:

```
constexpr auto c = get_thing_string(static_cast<things>(12));  // error
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xYKr51).

---

Note that in c++20, you can make the function `consteval` and then compilation will fail in all cases, since the function *must* be evaluated at compile time.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jEvGY1).